# Navigation bar background image remains overwritten by background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, background-color

Trying to create a simple tabbed site using Bootstrap, and I would like the navigation bar at the top to have a background image. However, the background image never appears. This is unlikely to be a path issue, since (a) the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) finds the relative path properly in the project, and (b) image URL using `http://...` doesn't work either. It seems the background-image property never gets recognized.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
.navbar > .container .navbar-brand, .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
  margin-left: -8px;
  height: 46px;  <!-- navbar-height -->
}

.navbar-custom {
  background: rgba(52, 73, 94, 0.7);  <!-- navbar-bgcolor -->
  background-image: url("https://jessicasse.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/distant-lights-1-1152x8641.jpg");
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;  <!-- heading font -->
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-kerning: auto;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;  <!-- heading font -->
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .current > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .current > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .current > a:focus {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: ghostwhite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="My Home Page">
  
  <title>My Home Page</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/font-awesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
  
  <!-- Custom Fonts -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/fonts/Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/fonts/Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic.css">

</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <div>
        <a style="color: ghostwhite; font-size: xx-large; font-weight: lighter" href="">This Page</a>
        <br>
        <p>
          <span style="color: ghostwhite; font-size: medium; font-weight: lighter">Job Title</span><br>
          <span style="color: ghostwhite; font-size: medium; font-weight: lighter">Company</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="research.html">Research</a></li>
        <li><a href="teaching.html">Teaching</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

I understand that (and please correct me if I am mistaken) `main.css` should override specifications in `bootstrap.css`. But, if I remove the `background: rgba(52, 73, 94, 0.7);` line from `main.css`, the result is just the default specified in `boostrap.css` (which is Bootstrap v3.3.4, in case that is relevant here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may have been caused by

1. The image being very big. You can use the `background-size` property to ensure it will fit into the space.

or

2. The formatting of your comments was wrong. In CSS, comments look like this: /* a comment */

```css
.navbar > .container .navbar-brand, .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
  margin-left: -8px;
  height: 46px;  
}

.navbar-custom {
  background: rgba(52, 73, 94, 0.7);  
  background-image: url("https://jessicasse.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/distant-lights-1-1152x8641.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif; 
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-kerning: auto;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;  <!-- heading font -->
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .current > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .current > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .current > a:focus {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: ghostwhite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="My Home Page">
  
  <title>My Home Page</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/font-awesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
  
  <!-- Custom Fonts -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/fonts/Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/fonts/Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic.css">

</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <div>
        <a style="color: ghostwhite; font-size: xx-large; font-weight: lighter" href="">This Page</a>
        <br>
        <p>
          <span style="color: ghostwhite; font-size: medium; font-weight: lighter">Job Title</span><br>
          <span style="color: ghostwhite; font-size: medium; font-weight: lighter">Company</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="research.html">Research</a></li>
        <li><a href="teaching.html">Teaching</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It was the wrong comment format!! I only introduced those comments so that I can later move to sass instead of just css, and completely forgot that this was not a HTML file!